# Optimizing Vectorized Transformation on NumPy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that performs a matrix transformation on a NumPy array, and I'm interested in optimizing its performance by eliminating a loop and taking full advantage of NumPy's vectorized operations. The function `transformation(current_tuple)` takes a 1D tuple `current_tuple` and returns a 2x2 array.

**MWE:**

```
import numpy as np

def transformation(current_tuple):
    return np.array([[current_tuple[0]  ,   current_tuple[1]],
                    [   0              ,   3.*current_tuple[0]]])

array_with_two_rows = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 6)) # Example 2D array

transformation_result = np.vstack([transformation(x) for x in array_with_two_rows.T])

print('true')
```

Currently, I apply the `transformation()` function to each column using a **for-loop**.

**Question:** I'm interested in finding a more efficient and vectorized alternative to achieve the same result without the need for a loop.

**PS:** The transformation logic is just a dummy logic to represent that a higher dimension matrix will be returned after transformation. The ***transformation logic is subject to change***. The only thing valid about the transformation logic is that it will take a row vector/array as input and return a two-dimensional array as output (could be 2x2, 2 x 5, 3 x 7 etc.).

Comment: how complex is your `transformation` function, can you post it?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Almost same function, just the number of rows and cols are different with different organization of elements, but no other logic is involved. The main thing to know is that the `transformation` function will always return a 2D array.

Comment: describe the logic of transformating/shuffling values in your function

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: The transformation logic to compute the elements of the array can change to anything. I don't know about it. If the answer is going to be bound to the transformation logic then, there is no solution to this problem.

Comment: I dont know why there were duplicates. Also I you should explain why you perceive the code to be wrong. ie `vectorized_transformation(arr).reshape(-1,2)` as long as the transformation results in `n*4` array

Comment: Your problem is not realizing that the vectorized_transformation. Eg, given any 2*1, matrix, you could transform the way you want without for-loops

Comment: All transformation are logic specific..

Comment: @Onyambu: The problem is not transformation specific. The question is about appending rows to a matrix without using for-loop. The source of rows could be anything. For example, the input could be `[time, location]` and the output is the rows containing user data (each row with 5 columns).

Comment: But still it will depend on how the rows should be appended. ie in that case, you will be merging. still problem specific. another person will have a input `[x,y]` and output 4 values, where the values are the squares and cubes of the input. How to solve this last problem and the problem of obtaining the user details will be completely different.

Comment: @Onyambu: If an optimized solution has to depend on the transformation logic then, there is no solution to this problem, and I must use the `for-loop` approach. In my scenario, the transformation logic may change frequently so, binding the `row-append` logic to the transformation logic would make the code error-prone.

Comment: I just dont understand your question per se. It seems that your current transformation function takes in a tuple and returns a 2d array. Note that your function is not vectorized. Thats all. Instead of writing your current transformation function in a non-vectorized manner, write the same transformation function with the same logic  in a vectorized manner. Thats all you have to do. Dont think of other transformation functions. think of the one you have, and make it vectorized

Comment: @Onyambu: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comments. Yes, that would work for me. Thanks. Please post your answer.

Comment: There is really no other answer. Unless you post the transformation logic. Your current transformation logic is simple multiplication. Note you stated that the logic will return a 2*3, 2*5. etc. A function will carry out the same logic to all inputs given to it. If you getting different sized arrays, does that mean the input are also different sized? if so are the inputs in an array or a list? the best idea i can think of it to do `np.vectorized(your_transformation)` which should be similar if not alittle better than a plain for-loop

Comment: @Onyambu: All inputs will be of same size (always single row) and all outputs will also be of same size.

Comment: Then to get a solution, you need to provide the transformation logic. ie how to get from the input to the output

Comment: @Onyambu: The answer to my question is, "do the vectorization of the transformation function". For the current answer, we can do the vectorization of the current transformation logic.

Comment: I don't see why you are using numpy at all. Your transform function can return a nested list, and the results get a further nesting in a list comprehension.  Pretending to use arrays instead of lists doesn't  improve performance.

Comment: @hpaulj: At the end, I need to have the results as numpy array because I want to process the data at GPU using cuPy. But it would be fine to use anything else to compute `transformation_result`, which can later be converted to numpy/cupy array.

Answer (score 1):

Related to my comment about using lists instead of arrays, let's define a version of your function that returns a list of lists:

```
In [251]: def trans_list(x):
     ...:     return [[x[0], x[1]], [0, 3.*x[0]]]
     ...:
```

Your original calculation, using a `array_with_two_rows` that I used in previous (deleted) answers:

```
In [252]: np.vstack([transformation(x) for x in array_with_two_rows.T])
Out[252]: 
array([[ 9.,  9.],
       [ 0., 27.],
       [ 8.,  7.],
       [ 0., 24.],
       [ 9.,  0.],
       [ 0., 27.],
       [ 5.,  5.],
       [ 0., 15.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  3.],
       [ 6.,  5.],
       [ 0., 18.]])

In [253]: timeit np.vstack([transformation(x) for x in array_with_two_rows.T])
96.6 µs ± 2.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Trying the same array, but in in list mode (`tolist()` is quite efficient in converting array to list):

```
In [254]: [trans_list(x) for x in array_with_two_rows.T.tolist()]
Out[254]: 
[[[9, 9], [0, 27.0]],
 [[8, 7], [0, 24.0]],
 [[9, 0], [0, 27.0]],
 [[5, 5], [0, 15.0]],
 [[1, 1], [0, 3.0]],
 [[6, 5], [0, 18.0]]]

In [255]: timeit [trans_list(x) for x in array_with_two_rows.T.tolist()]
5.63 µs ± 11.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

So much faster.  Often for small stuff, python list operations are faster, especially if they skip making small arrays.  I can imagine redoing this as a for loop with `extend` to remove a level of list nesting.

Even when I add the `vstack` back in, it is still faster:

```
In [256]: np.vstack([trans_list(x) for x in array_with_two_rows.T.tolist()])
Out[256]: 
array([[ 9.,  9.],
       [ 0., 27.],
       [ 8.,  7.],
       [ 0., 24.],
       [ 9.,  0.],
       [ 0., 27.],
       [ 5.,  5.],
       [ 0., 15.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  3.],
       [ 6.,  5.],
       [ 0., 18.]])

In [257]: timeit np.vstack([trans_list(x) for x in array_with_two_rows.T.tolist()])
45.5 µs ± 156 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The usual time disclaimer applies; alternatives may scale differently.

And the array multiplication approach that I suggested earlier does quite well, since it's working with the numpy whole-array methods directly:

```
In [258]: (x[:,None,:] * np.array([[1,1],[0,3]])).reshape(-1,2)
Out[258]: 
array([[ 9,  9],
       [ 0, 27],
       [ 8,  7],
       [ 0, 21],
       [ 9,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 5,  5],
       [ 0, 15],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 0,  3],
       [ 6,  5],
       [ 0, 15]])

In [259]: timeit (x[:,None,:] * np.array([[1,1],[0,3]])).reshape(-1,2)
15.9 µs ± 21 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: A bit confused with your answer (pardon my less Python experience). Could you post in your answer how do I get the `transformation_result` without `for-loop`?

Comment: Compare your transformation function with the result of a simple multiplication, `array_with_two_rows[:,1]*np.array([[1,1],[0,3]])`.  With a little understanding of how arrays `broadcast` with each other that can be extened to the whole 2d array.